# FreeBSD: using python3 in uwsgi instead of python2

Tags: freebsd, python, python3, uwsgi

I have a server with FreeBSD 10.1 installed. I want to deploy a Django site on it using uwsgi+nginx+python3 and got some problems.

The site was written for python3, I installed python3.4 then python3 and python from ports, configured nginx and wrote uwsgi ini-file and sock-file.
I then tried to start the project. It works perfecttly in virtualenv.

Then I installed uwsgi globally using pip3. 
But when I try to start the project globally I get the error

```
no module named site
```

which means that uwsgi uses python2 instead of 3. 
What I tried to resolve this problem:

- set DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=3.4 in make.conf;
- set $PYTHONHOME and $PYTHONPATH to /usr/local/bin/python3;
- change link /usr/local/bin/python from python2 to python3;

It didn't help.
How to force uwsgi to use python3 instead of python2?

PS photo of terminal: http://prntscr.com/9os1f2

Comment: It looks like uwsgi sets `PythonPath` when it runs, presumably for its own bundled version of Python. I don't use uwsgi so I don't know for sure, but there should be either a) a setting to change that or b) manually replace their Python 2 executable with a symlink to your Python 3 executable.

Comment: When setting `DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=3.4` in `make.conf` what exactly did you do? Did you rebuild the port?

Comment: This ^^ ... it should help set a compile-time option; something akin to 'CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/python3.4" make PYTHON=python3.4 asyncio' ... if the port hasn't been rebuilt, that's the first thing to try.  make.conf should take over and set the flags for you.

Comment: @Raphael You're right, I forgot to rebuilt the port after changing make.conf. Foolishly, but I'm new in UNIX. Add you comment to answers and I'll commit it.

Comment: @DiA I added my answer so it is easier to spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting

```
DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=3.5 python2=2.7 python3=3.5
```

in `/etc/make.conf` you have to rebuild the ports that use the default version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtualenv` to handle different Python versions on one server, and use completely separate Python installations for whatever you need.

See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/