# How to change the default (binary) python version in a FreeBSD jail?

Tags: freebsd, python, version, jails, python3

In a jail, I have installed `python3.6` along `python3.4`. Both were installed using `pkg install`, no ports. I want to keep the 3.4 version for some time, but set the 3.6 as default.

Answers found in internet, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349831/how-to-set-python-version-by-default-in-freebsd) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254660/freebsd-using-python3-in-uwsgi-instead-of-python2) either involve to myself link `/usr/local/bin/python` to `python3.6` (what must be done again after any upgrade of the default python, what I'd like to avoid; plus there's no such link anyway); or to set `DEFAULT_VERSIONS` in `/etc/make.conf`, what has no effects on binaries installation (I've tried, nevertheless).

Moreover, the virtual environment is not an option, since I want to run `uwsgi`, what requires the *system wide* default python to match the one in the python virtual environment of the python application it "monitors" (in my case, Django), in order to start correctly. Even if I start from inside the Django's virtual environment (providing python3.6), `uwsgi` detects `python3.4` as the default python version.

Cannot find if there is any environment variable missing neither.

For information, inside the jail (and virtual environment):

```
# printenv 
USER=root
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/csh
BLOCKSIZE=K
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/venv/dj1/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
TERM=xterm-256color
HOSTTYPE=FreeBSD
VENDOR=amd
OSTYPE=FreeBSD
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/var/log
GROUP=wheel
HOST=dev_web0
EDITOR=vi
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
MM_CHARSET=UTF-8
PAGER=more
VIRTUAL_ENV=/usr/local/venv/dj1
```

Comment: 1st possible workaround for uwsgi: instead of installing it in the jail with pkg, install it along with Django in the same virtual environment (inside the venv: `pip install uwsgi`). If it is run as a service, edit the relevant startup script (like `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/uwsgid`) to let it start/stop/reload... uwsgi in the right venv.

Comment: 2d possible workaround for uwsgi (just a guess, I didn't try): create the desired plugins (see http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary) and force uwsgi to use the right version in uwsgi.ini (for instance, add: plugins = python36)

Comment: Yet none of my 2 workarounds above do answer the question. For instance, when I install python36, it ends up mentionning: """"

Message from py36-setuptools-32.1.0_1:
*******************************************************************

  Only /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.6 script has been installed
  since Python 3.6 is not the default Python version.
"""

Comment: Have you tried to set your PYTHONPATH to the desired python install?

Answer (score 0):

All binaries were prebuilt with default settings and current default Python is 3.6.

To achieve your goal you can install desired Python version as a binary then you can set it in `DEFAULT_VERSIONS` in `/etc/make.conf` and then install `uwsgi` from ports using this version. I do this procedure in automated way with `Python3.7` which is't default ATM.

Alternatively, you can test if your application works fine under `Python 3.6` (upgrade to your code should be minimal if any) and continue with default binaries.

Comment: So far, I just use my 1st workaround, even if it does not really solve the case, because at least it lets things work. I do not want to use the ports on this box, that's why I did not set `DEFAULT_VERSIONS` in `/etc/make.conf` (or, rather, I did, but in vain). I do not remember why keeping `3.4` was required (would indeed solve everything if I could simply remove it), but it was not by my application, what required `3.6`.

Comment: Actually, I use it on a virtual build environment to build packages with my own settings. Later I install them to a few target machines.